# Disable checkbox if form is invalid or empty and enable if valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, angular-forms

I have an angular form with few text fields. I have a checkbox below the fields.

I want to disable the checkbox if the fields in the form are empty or invalid.

The html code of checkbox is include below.I tried the [disabled] = "form.invalid". When I use it this way the checkbox gets disabled and error message appears.

Also, I tried this approach of adding  a function **[disabled]="!areDetailsInvalid()" in .ts file.**

```
 public updateValidity(_event: Event) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.formIsValid = this.form.valid;
    }, 0);
}
 public areDetailsInvalid()
{
    return this.formIsValid;
}   


<mat-checkbox disableRipple class="head checkboxlabel mat-warn" [checked]="saveAsCheckbox" [disabled]="!areDetailsInvalid()" (change)="toggleSaveAs()">
                                        <span class="save-as-checkbox-label">Check to save {{saveAsLabel}} information</span>
                                    </mat-checkbox>
```

The checkbox is disabled if the form is invalid.  But not enabled again if the form is valid.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz.com for this?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this example would help you.

Let me know if this solves your issue.

Stackblitz => https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enhthy